# sequence converging to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

If ${(x_n)^{1/n}}$ converges to 1, then can we say that ${x_n}$ also converges to 1? We know that ${x_n}$ is a convergent sequence.

Comment: The answer is no. A counterexample is  $x_n = n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic counterexample : $ \left(x_{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} :$

We have : $$ x_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+\frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1 $$

But : $$ x_{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=\exp{\left(\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\exp{\left(1\right)}=\mathrm{e} $$